# google maps pin markers not showing when I open the html file

Tags: python, marker, gmplot

I have a python file where I am using gmplot  to create custom markers on gmaps.  I save it as an HTML file.  It works fine when I open the file in my computer.  However when I try to open it in my phone or send it by email and try to open on another computer all the pins disappear.  The map loads centered exactly where it is supposed to be.  Here is the code

```
import gmplot
import pandas as pd
import random
newdir = r'C:\Users\.spyder-py3'
newfile = r'\EWMP List 2019 Addresses.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(newdir+newfile)
#colors=pd.read_csv(newdir+r'\html_colors.csv')
#color_list=[]
# html colors is a csv file with hexa codes for different colors
# I am suppressing the randomizer and hardcoding the colors here to see if that works.  It doesn't
#for i, k in enumerate(random.sample(range(len(colors)),10)):
#    color_list.append(colors['Hex Code'][k])
placetypelist=df['placetype'].unique().tolist()
#In the original code, I cycle through the placetype_list and color_list append them to the color_dict as #key and item  
# As you can see below I am hardcoding this dictionary
color_dict={'Greenway': '#FF0000',
 'Miscellaneous': '#AFEEEE',
 'Natural Restoration': '#DA70D6',
 'School': '#3CB371',
 'golf course': '#191970',
 'green street': '#EE82EE',
 'park and open space': '#808080',
 'parking lot': '#F8F8FF',
 'school': '#C71585',
 'unknown land parcel': '#1E90FF'}
#for i in range(len(color_list)):
#     color_dict[placetypelist[i]] = (color_list[i])
latlist=df['resolved_lat'].tolist()
lnglist=df['resolved_lng'].tolist()
gmaps=gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latlist[0],lnglist[0],zoom=13,apikey=<myAPIkeyasstring>)     
for i in range(len(latlist)):
    gmaps.marker(latlist[i],lnglist[i],c=color_dict[df['placetype'][i]], title=str(i)+df['placetype'][i])
gmaps.draw(newdir+r'\laconcise_alt.html')
```

When I open the file in chrome from this directory it opens **with the pins**.[image]

But when I send it as an email attachment and try to open it from another terminal I get the map **without the pins**.  What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer thanks to the excellent work in this github link

[t.ly/DZX03](https://github.com/vgm64/gmplot/pull/110/commits/5683d263aef0ece2c93ef0e010425b25c9ad6071)

Let's say you are using the logic that I am using where you work off of hexacodes through a CSV file for html color.  Typically, you will have a csv of colors used in matplotlib (140, I think).  The gmplot module has a color_dict file that has not updated all the matplotlib colors.  It is going to throw an error if you use a hexa code that is not there in their list.  So please update the color_dict file at your end, before you work off of a random csv file like I did.  I think the better option would be to import the html color codes form the color_dict file in your code and work with that.